# Trying to move to a new view in swiftUI after a button press

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am trying to create an application which has the ability to create and view assignments. I have a page called AddAssignment.swift and ViewAssignment.swift, and I am trying to move from the AddAssignment page to the ViewAssignment page on a button press.

The user should enter the details in the text boxes, and then when the button is pressed, I want to save the information in the text box and move to the View Assignments screen. So far, I am not able to get the button to work correctly.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddAssignment: View {
    
    // Properties
    @State var taskName = ""
    @State var dueDate = ""
    @State var subject = ""
    @State var weighting = ""
    @State var totalMarks = ""
    
    // Methods
    
    func saveTask(a:String,b:String,c:String,d:String,e:String) -> [String] {
        
        var newTask: [String] = []
        
        newTask.append(a);
        newTask.append(b);
        newTask.append(c);
        newTask.append(d);
        newTask.append(e);

        return newTask
        
    }
    
    
    // Main UI
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text("Add New Task")
                .font(.headline)
                .padding()
                .scaleEffect(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/2.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Image(systemName: "plus.app.fill")
                .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                .scaleEffect(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/5.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Group { // Text Fields
            
            TextField("Enter assignment name", text: $taskName)
                .padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])
                
            
            
            TextField("Enter due date", text: $dueDate)
                .padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])
            
            
            
            TextField("Enter subject", text: $subject)
                .padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])
            
            
            TextField("Enter percent weighting", text: $weighting)
                .padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])
            
            
            TextField("Enter total marks", text: $totalMarks)
                .padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])
                
            }
            
           Spacer()
            
    
            Button("Create New Task", action: {
                
                let task: [String] = [taskName, dueDate, subject, weighting, totalMarks]
                print(task)
                ViewAssignment()
                
            })
            
            
            
            Spacer()
                    
        }
    }
    

}


struct AddAssignment_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddAssignment()
    }
}
```

The console is able to return the values of the textbooks and store this information, I'm just not sure how to bring that across to another struct in the ViewAssignment.swift file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make the "move work", add this to "AddAssignment":

```
struct AddAssignment: View {
    @State var toAssignment: Int? = nil
```

replace your Button("Create New Task", action: {...}, with

```
        NavigationLink(destination: ViewAssignment(), tag: 1, selection: $toAssignment) {
            Button("Create New Task") {
                let task: [String] = [taskName, dueDate, subject, weighting, totalMarks]
                print(task)
                self.toAssignment = 1
            }
        }
```

make sure you wrap the whole thing in "NavigationView { ...}"